# Is it possible to use setLayout() in an interface in order to "force" implementing classes to use a certain layout?

Tags: java, swing, interface

*I am still learning about interfaces, so my question might be kind of basic!*

I've [read a bit about interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and tried to toy around with them. One use case I came up with is to "force" implementing classes to use a certain layout.

Example:

I have several classes (page1, page2, ...) that extend `JPanel`. All of them use a `MigLayout` via `setLayout(new MigLayout())` in the constructor. If you forget to set the `MigLayout`, the classes might still work, might still look fairly normal or sometimes break completely. Therefore it is preferred to always set the same layout for all classes.

My idea was, to create an interface and put some methods into it, that are used in the classes, especially the `setLayout(new MigLayout())`-method so you wont forget to use this method in your class.

But this will give me the error:

> Syntax error on token "setLayout", @ expected before this token

I also tried to use an anonymous inner class in the interface:

```
ForcedLayout testLayout = new ForcedLayout(){
{
    setLayout(new MigLayout());
}};
```

But I did not find any way to use `testLayout` in the implementing classes and therefore force the layout.

So:

- Is it possible to "force" the implementing classes to use a specific layout via the interface?
- Does it make sense at all to use this approach? (Approach = I kind of use interfaces to not forget to use certain methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the classes are extending `JPanel` hence you can create your own `MigLayoutPanel` that extends `JPanel` and have `MigLayout` already set.

```
public abstract class MigLayoutPanel extends JPanel {

      public MigLayoutPanel() {
           this(new MigLayout());
      }

      private MigLayoutPanel(LayoutManager layout) {
           super(layout);
      }

      @Override
      public void setLayout(LayoutManager layout) {
          if(!(layout instanceof MigLayout)){
              throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not allowed to change the layout");
          }
      }
}
```

Now you custom classes.

```
public class MyPanel extends MigLayoutPanel {
    ....
}
```

---

Interface just declares or defines a contract (set of methods) that a concrete sub-class has to implement all of them. Java 7 supports [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) that enables you to add default functionality in interface itself.

Note: This is not a full proof solution. Any sub-class can override it.

Comment: Very good way to set the same layout to the classes! But my question is if I can use an interface to force the implementing classes to do this. I want to understand interfaces better.

Comment: You can use [interface default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) but that can be overridden in sub-classes that is not full proof solution

Comment: Ah, then I could do `setLayout(MigLayout migLayout)` in the interface and have the other classes implement it, with the downside of the method not being protected from being overridden. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it? I think, this is actually what I wanted to learn about interfaces.

Comment: Why not make MigLayoutPanel's setLayout method final - then subclasses cannot override it.

Comment: @FredK There is no need to do it. If sub-class overrides the `setLayout` method then what it can do to set a different layout. It has to call `super.setLayout()` that will ultimately call `MigLayoutPanel.setLayout()` where we have already added a type check on layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some base class (instead of interface) and let your other class extend this class?

So basically you write...

```
public class BaseLayOutClass extends JPanel
{ 
   public BaseLayOutClass()
   {
         // somebasic code if you want
        setLayout(new MigLayout());
   }
     // Have all other methods defined here.

}
```

and then you ask all to extend this class

```
public class Panel1 extends BaseLayOutClass 
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my question is about if I can use an Interface to force the implementing classes to set the layout. I want to understand interfaces more.

Comment: Even if you force interface and ask them to write a method, who will call that method? some base class itself. In interface you can't have implementation of methods

Comment: Good point, I can force the implementing class to **have** a certain method, but not force the class to **call** the method. Is this the reason, that I cant use `setLayout(new MigLayout())` directly in an interface?